# Convert video(any type) to audio -mp3 format- using python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, video, mp3

I'm working on a project, using Python running on Google App Engine. The project must allow users to upload video file then convert these files into mp3 audio file. Is there a way to convert this video to mp3/wav audio?

Could anyone offer a solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want todo this in Python, video convert requires working native modules which the App Engine doesn't support.
You can try to work 3rd party web service that do the convert for you, or send the convert task to an external server.

Comment: :you mean convert in external server and store the resulted file in GAE?

Comment: @Eng_Engineer or on S3 or in Google Cloud Storage, GAE can access both

Answer (score 2):

You could use FFMPEG for the conversion.

there is a python wrapper [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/)

or [pymedia](http://pymedia.org/)

Comment: @Eng_Engineer from the other posts here i guess not. You'd need a 3rd party service or your own server. You might be able to setup a really cheap VPS for it.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have trouble doing this on GAE, as libraries with native components aren't necessarily available there; it may well not be possible at all.

If targeting a more typical Python app server environment, rather than GAE, I would do this using the [GStreamer Python bindings](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html); GStreamer lets you set up a media pipeline (decoders/demuxers/encoders, etc), and is otherwise perfect for this application (other than platform availability).